# Как скачать файл по URL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, zip

Дано: URL https://op.mos.ru/EHDWSREST/catalog/export/get?id=84505
По ссылке лежит ZIP архив. Внутри JSON файл.

Задача: Сохранить файла JSON на диск. Считать данные с файла.

Вопрос: Подскажите пожалуйста пример как это сделать? Попытки использовать get.request возвращают ответ сервера Response [200]

```
def load_data(url):
   r = requests.get(url)
   return r

if __name__ == '__main__':

   url = 'https://op.mos.ru/EHDWSREST/catalog/export/get?id=84505'
   print(load_data(url))
```

Answer (score 3):

В этом примере все операции происходят в памяти (при желании без проблем можно сохранить на диск):

```
import json
import io
import zipfile

import requests


rs = requests.get('https://op.mos.ru/EHDWSREST/catalog/export/get?id=84505')
zip_data = io.BytesIO(rs.content)

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_data) as zip_file:
    json_file_name = zip_file.namelist()[0]
    print(json_file_name)
    # data-2897-2016-11-23.json

    json_data = zip_file.read(json_file_name)
    json_data = json_data.decode('cp1251')
    print(json_data[:50])
    # [{"global_id":20660594,"system_object_id":"0000693

    obj = json.loads(json_data)
    print(obj[0]['AdmArea'])
    # Центральный административный округ
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает отлично!

Answer (score 2):

**Вот так попробуйте**

```
from  urllib.request import urlopen 
import  zipfile 
import json

url = urlopen("https://op.mos.ru/EHDWSREST/catalog/export/get?   id=84505")    
f = url.read()
open("file.zip","wb").write(f)

z = zipfile.ZipFile('file.zip', 'r')
z.extractall()


with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for txt in data:
        print(txt)
```

Comment: Все заработало с небольшим дополнением. Спасибо за помощь!

`from urllib.request import urlopen 
import zipfile 
import json

def load_data(url):
    f = url.read()
    open("file.zip","wb").write(f)
    
    z = zipfile.ZipFile('file.zip', 'r')
    z.extractall()
    
    json_file_name = z.namelist()[0]
    
    with open(json_file_name, 'r', encoding='cp1251') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for txt in data:
            print(txt)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = urlopen("https://op.mos.ru/EHDWSREST/catalog/export/get?id=84505")
    load_data(url)`

Comment: отметьте ответ )